# Need to fetch only 1 record for the sql requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I need to fetch only one record for the id provided.
If the id is present in the table it will fetch that particular record and if it is not present, it will fetch the NULL valued record

Example
Table-: *demo_table*

```
id
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
(null)
```

For example if I am passing id as 1 it should return only 1st row, similarly If i am passing id as 4 it should fetch only 4th row but if I am passing id that is not there in the table, it should give me the 6th record i.e. NULL valued record.

I want this to be in Single SQL query. Thanks for your help in advance.
Let me know if you need more information.

Also , no ROWNUM, ROWID concept. Should be in 1 query, i.e. no MINUS,UNION etc

Comment: When you say NULL valued record, do you just want to fetch just the id or are there multiple columns? Sounds like you would like to just always get a row back and if the ID does not exist, you just want to have NULL returned rather than dealing with no rows returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got the requirement correctly you want to have either the ID back of NULL instead.

A very easy trick is the following:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM demo_table WHERE id = 4;
```

This will either return the id 4 or, if not present, it will return NULL instead. Given that you always include the ID in the WHERE clause, the MAX does not do much more than just handling the `NO ROWS FOUND` for you.

Comment: this will help me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select id from demo_table where id = 4
    union
    select null from dual
)
where rownum = 1
order by id DESC
```

Comment: we cant use rownum.

Comment: NO FAIR - you added that stipulation after I answered

Comment: yes, but that is our requirement, we cant use rownum in queries.

I forgot to mention that in the description, so added that now

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN id = 123 THEN 'NULL' ELSE id END id
  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR (NVL (MIN (id), '123')) AS id
          FROM my_table
         WHERE id = 6)
```

**Update 1**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (id) IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE id END id,
       CASE WHEN ename IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE ename END ename
  FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR (id) id, ename
          FROM my_table
         WHERE id = 6
        UNION
        SELECT NULL, NULL
          FROM DUAL
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (SELECT id, ename
                     FROM my_table
                    WHERE id = 6))
```

Comment: @user3721687 Accept and upvote if you find this useful and correct.

Comment: Query is correct but if i need to get the complete NULL row then?  if more columns are there and i need to get the 2nd column.

Comment: @user3721687 Could you elaborate?

Comment: with id we have one more column - 'value'
and i need to fetch the value column for the mentioned condition above.

Comment: @user3721687 Replace ename with your column from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.* from 
 ( select * from demo_table 
       where id = 4 or id is null) as t
 where t.id = 
  ( IF EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM demo_table WHERE ID = 4) 
             SELECT 4 
          ELSE 
             SELECT null )  ;
```

Comment: That will return nothing if `id = 4` is not in the table.

Comment: will not work bro, bcz if i am passing any other id which is not there in table then it will not fetch any record.(NO_DATA_FOUND)